# Using * in lm for variables with common names

Tags: r

If I have 100 variables with a common name, such as year_1951, year_1952, year_1953 etc, is there a way to do a linear regression that includes all variables that start with year_  ?  In Stata this is easy by using the *, but in R, I'm not sure how to go about this.

THanks.

Stata Example :

`regress y year_`*

Is there an equivalence in R, such as

```
ols.lm <- lm(y ~ year_*, data = d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think R support that kind of expansion inside formula. It do support y ~ . kind of expansion.

Here is how you can do it

```
variables <- colnames(d)
depVar <- 'y'
indepVars <- variables[grepl('^year_',variables)]
myformulae <- as.formula(paste(depVar,paste(indepVars,collapse=' + '),sep = ' ~ '))
modelfit <-lm(myformulae,data=d)
```

**Edit**
: Solving the problem mentioned in the comment (Adding constants in the formulae)

```
variables <- colnames(d)
depVar <- 'y'
indepVars <- variables[grepl('^year_',variables)]
indepVarsCollapse <- paste(paste(indepVars,collapse=' + '), '-1')
myformulae <- as.formula(paste(depVar,indepVarsCollapse,sep = ' ~ '))
modelfit <-lm(myformulae,data=d)
```

Comment: You might want to add ^ before year in the following expression to make sure you only select variables that start with year and choose variables that contain year anywhere in the variable name as follows: indepVars <- variables[grepl('^year_',variables)]

Comment: This works.  THanks!  But how do I use this with no constant?  for examples ols.lm <- lm(y~x - 1, data=d) I can't figure out how to add in the -1 to the formula.

Comment: @Amstell Please take a look at the edited answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you!  This worked, so I'll submit as an answer, but I still feel a pretty significant limitation in R.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than selecting the columns in the formula, select them in the data argument:

```
nms <- c("y", grep("year_", names(d), value = TRUE))
lm(y ~., d[nms])
```

Alternately, select all the desired columns in the `grep`

```
ix <- grep("^(y$|year_)", names(d))
lm(y ~., d[ix])
```

or if we knew that the unwanted columns do not start with y:

```
ix <- grep("^y", names(d))
lm(y ~., d[ix])
```